# How to echo message if no row count

Tags: php, count, echo

I am trying to echo the message 'No records found' when I get nothing back from the database.

I have done a row count which shows me how many rows I have but I can't seem to echo the 'No records found' message. Is it in the wrong place? Will it not run for some reason?

```
    <?php if(isset($search_results)){
   foreach($search_results as $result) {
       $rowcount = $result['rowcount'];
  if(!$rowcount < 1) {
      echo $rowcount;
         echo '<div class="search_result"> <b>'.$result['title'].'</b><br />';
   echo '<span class="search_result_url">'.$result['link'].'</span><br />';
  echo $result['text'].'<br /></div>';

  } else {
    echo  'No records found.';
  } 
    }
    } else {
        echo 'Use the search to find what you are looking for. Enter the term or keyord into the search box and press enter..';
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Just check for `if ($rowcount > 0) {`

Comment: The code suggests that you may be unclear as to whether $search_results is an array of rows (in which case $search_results itself is your "result set") or if it is an array of arrays, each of which has a 'rowcount' field (and who knows what else). It would be helpful if you could describe exactly the format of the data which you expect to find inside the $search_results array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [`mysql_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), and use an `if()` to see whether your `mysql_query()` returned any results:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    echo 'No results';
}
else
{
    // Results - do stuff.
}
```