# Error echo count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, echo

I know the topic has been treated in many questions, but I could not find the solution.
I have read and tried many topics,(like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651535/php-echo-sql-count), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954298/how-to-echo-message-if-no-row-count)) but none seem to work on my page. 
The echo always returns 0 (while the data is 40)

here is my code:

```
$BIS = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Voti 
        WHERE sito='$sito' AND utente='$utente'";

#$topics= mysql_query($BIS); 
#echo $topics['count'];    <- this doesn't work

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($BIS)){
    echo $row['count'];   <- this doesn't work
}


if($topics['count']==0){   <- ever 0
$query = " INSERT INTO `Voti` (`utente`,`sito`,`voto`) 
           VALUES ('$email','$sito', $voto)";
mysql_query($query);
}
```

Sorry for duplicate entry, but i don't found the error
p.s. sorry for my bad english

Comment: you have comment your sql connection.  which is this line "#$topics= mysql_query($BIS); "

Comment: it's simple another attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not run query try to run with `mysql_query()` try

```
$BIS = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Voti WHERE sito='$sito' AND utente='$utente'";

$topics= mysql_query($BIS); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($topics)){
```

or try for count rows

```
$BIS = "SELECT * FROM Voti WHERE sito='$sito' AND utente='$utente'";

    $topics= mysql_query($BIS); 
$count = mysql_num_rows($topics);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. width:
$BIS = "SELECT * FROM Voti WHERE sito='$sito' AND utente='$utente'";
$topics= mysql_query($BIS); 
$count = mysql_num_rows($topics);

echo $count;

stamp ever 0

Comment: then your query doesn't return any rows please echo your query and check conditions is matched

Comment: i've just tryed. Witring the query on phpMyAdmin, it  give me 40 entryes, not 0

Comment: EDIT
A very stupid error... I'm Wrong on the variables name -.-
thanks very much!!